# Separating time elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clock, slice

i am trying to build a clock app, with the concept of replacing numbers with images.

My approach was to split the hours into two elements along with the minutes.

For example --> 02:30 into --> 0,2 : 3,0

The slice method isn't working

```
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();

h=checkTime(h);
m=checkTime(m);
h1 = h.slice(0,1);
console.log(h);
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: you are returning numbers and trying to use a string method on them, numerous ways to convert to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var h1 = Math.floor(h / 10),
    h2 = h % 10;
```

Comment: `parseInt()` is the slowest method for truncation. Use `Math.floor()` instead.

Comment: Use / encourage the usage of `var` when declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use toString(); and substring instead if you want to get each "number" inside of the timespan

Comment: for toString()..it doesnt consider 0 i think in "04"

Answer (score 0):

Get hours and minutes, convert the integer by toString and split it. (You don't even have to split, you could access each letter / sign of a string simply by h[0] and so on):

```
var d = new Date(),
    h = ((h = d.getHours()) < 10 ? '0' + h : h).toString().split(''),
    m = ((m = d.getMinutes()) < 10 ? '0' + m : m).toString().split('');


// testing
console.log(h);
console.log(m);
```

Comment: This is probably the most roundabout way to get two digits of a number.

Comment: @AtesGoral you are right, thanks for pointing that. I put together a small test: http://jsperf.com/converting-time. The ranking is clear and self speaking: Math.floor, parseInt, toString and at the very end toString in combination with split.

Answer (score 0):

No need to deal with string manipulation:

```
var h1 = Math.floor(h / 10);
var h2 = h % 10;
```